# Script to clean cells from rows where another column is not blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Right now I have a simple script to clean a range of cells and set value after clear content in multiple google sheets:

```
function clearRanges() {
 var range = SpreadsheetApp
               .getActive()
               .getSheetByName("Xin hàng")
               .getRangeList(['A3:L2000']) 

 // Configure what to clear in the range
 var options = {
   formatOnly: false,
   contentsOnly: true
 };

 range.clear(options);

 SpreadsheetApp.flush();
 Utilities.sleep(10000);
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Xin hàng");
 var khoxuat = ss.getRangeList(['G3:G2000']);
 khoxuat.setValue('=iferror(INDEX(Mapping!$E:$E;MATCH(iferror(LEFT($A3;4)&DATEVALUE($H3)&MID($B3;3;7)&RIGHT($B3)&"TRUE";"");Mapping!$G:$G;0));"")');
 var trangthaipdc = ss.getRangeList(['J3:J2000']);
 trangthaipdc.setValue('=IF(I3<>"";"Open";"")');
}
```

I want to insert a code in that script to blank/clear (not delete them) entire row from row #3 to row #2000 where column ​'L' is not blank.

[Here is the example of this case](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wN-UIGmmBY8CZ-1cDkbQrtn-zB_rZD7oWjJ1GB-5jpo/edit?usp=sharing)

My knowledge in script is very limited and can't figure out how to do it, can you help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: About `I want to insert a code in that script to blank/clear (not delete them) entire row from row #3 to row #2000 where column ​'L' is not blank.`, in your showing script, `A3:L2000` is cleared by `range.clear(options);`. So, I'm worried that in this case, even when the script for this is inserted, your goal cannot be achieved. How about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Delete Row if L Col is not empty:

I understand that you are trying to create a script or add a script in there that would clear the contents of a row if the value of the L column is not blank when run. I have created a script you can use when called and get you on the right direction. Here is the code for you:

### Sample Code:

```
function clearCellUsingL() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // please put the name of the sheet you want to edit inside the ("").
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:L2000"); 
  var currentData = range.getValues();

 currentData.forEach(function(row, index) {
  if (row[11] !== "") { /* Check if column L is not blank. 
Please do take note that row [11] is the direct array placer for column L and 
can be adjusted accordingly, just count from A to your desired column.*/
    var rowIndex = index + 3;
    sheet.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent(); // your clear contents code
  }
});
  
}
```

You can just adjust your code accordingly to call these function depending on which situation you need it. Please do keep in mind as well that due to the number of columns being processed when the code is running it might be slower than what you have expected.

### Test Results:

[image]

### Reference:

[ClearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)

[For Each](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/boolean-condition)